# What is the difference between RAIL and SFL lights?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules

What is the difference between Runway Alignment Indicator Lights (RAIL) and Sequenced Flashing Lights (SFL)?

Both of them are same in terms of flashing light.

Comment: From Wikipedia: "RAIL are similar to sequenced flashing lights, except that they end where the white approach light bars begin."

Answer (score 4):

SFL start at the decision bar. RAILs may not.  The key differentiating factor is that RAILs extend beyond the centerline lights.

Comment: Thank you for answer. In the other words,SFL is embedded in ALS, on the  other hand RAIL is outside of ALS. Is it right?

Comment: @Aviat Lol! "Hand rail" had me confused for a second. [forehead slap]

Comment: There are RAILs and REILs. Had a instrument student get dinged on that once.